# Should an irrigation manifold/valve box be situated in the yard (centipede) or landscaping (pine straw)?

Tags: landscaping, irrigation, backyard, lawn, grass

In fixing a broken irrigation system, the manifold and all valves have been disconnected and will be relocated in at least some way. The previous setup used round access portals and was neglected for years. At least one of the portals was less than one foot away from the root-center of a bush. All of the portals were located in poorly-maintained pine-straw-based landscaping, and one of the portals was completely covered over with dirt, grass over the dirt, and pine straw over the grass, such that it wasn't discovered until a larger excavation was in process to look for a completely separate component.

In the interest of improving an already-being-repaired system, there is consideration to replace the three round access portals with a single rectangular access box. This box would be near the previous location, but could be in the pine straw, or be moved to the centipede-based lawn. If moved into the lawn, it could be anywhere from one to five feet from the landscape edging, although there is a driveway at a distance of eight feet from the likely point where the edging will be. (Edging also up for potential shifting one way or the other.)

In the interest of following best practices ([via the only link found this far in the subject](https://www.irrigation.org/IA/Advocacy/Standards-Best-Practices/Landscape-Irrigation-BMPs/IA/Advocacy/Landscape-Irrigation-BMPs.aspx), which is unclear on this particular point), should the box be in the pine-straw-based landscaping, or in the centipede-grass lawn? (If there are notable pros or cons to either, please share for the sake of us unfamiliar with this subject...)

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason you haven’t received any answers it is an opinion on where things should go, just like the valve close to the bush (the bush was probably planted later). I like the valves to be closer to the house not in the lawn that way the landscaping can hide them if there out in the lawn you will be able to see the box it may not matter to you but more often they are out of sight.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that they usually "disappear" , so the main consideration is put them where you or a service guy can find them; such as in a straight row, or next to a sidewalk. I try to take photos to show locations and the pipe orientations .